# Trying to Google Sign-In for android appilcation, i get "There was an unknown error"

Tags: android, google-signin

I was trying to enable Google Sign-In for one of my android applications, I have followed the steps to generate SHA1 Key from the application keystore with the correct password.
When i tried to use the code in Googles developer website i keep getting the message :

***There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.***

I am stuck , the error message doesn't tell me any thing to work with or where to look for the error!

Thank you

Comment: Which code were you using? Can you update your question with a link? I've been going over [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), but I've noticed that the code it uses is now deprecated.

Comment: Problem is in the service authentication stage, there is no code involved yet.

Comment: You said you used the code from the developer website. What code did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This problem mostly arise if we logged in with multiple google accounts.
Logout from all accounts and login from your primary account.
You see this as refrence
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867841/7062071