# Firebase: There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

I'm just trying to creating new project in Firebase but getting this error every time.

[image]

Comment: I've encountered same error. It most likely connection problem, you should try again. **Note:** I think you also want to check to http://console.developers.google.com because that error might created 1 extra project on Google API, but failed to save on Firebase (that's happen to me)

Comment: I am able to create project using incognito just now

Answer (score 37):

What I did was sign out from Firebase and sign back in again. This worked.

The project was already created. The problem occurred because maybe the Firebase console was unable to sync or refresh, but signing out and back in worked for me. Try that.

Comment: Try refreshing cache

Answer (score 18):

[image: Disable CORS Plugin]

My solution was to disable an Allow CORS plugin on Firefox.  I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 11):

I have this issue as well however, it was because of an outage in the Firebase service. To check for outages, go to: https://status.firebase.google.com

You can see there are red dots which shows the outage in the Firebase console.

[image]

Clicking on the red dot will provide you with a status on what's going on.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Signing out and then back in didn't work for me. Even worse, my projects were created somehow in the background and then I finally got an error message that told me I reached a limit and wouldn't be able to create any new projects any more.

I got emails though informing me about a "Project Shutdown Announcement". I clicked the link there and landed on a site that listed all these projects that had been created in the background although the error message "There was an unknown error while processing the request" would indicate otherwise.

I restored one of the projects there and used that. Hope that helps.

Comment: True, just happened to me I signed out using Chrome and back in and the projects where not there. I didn't restart the Chrome app though, maybe that would have worked, instead I switched to Safari and logged in and 3 new projects all with the same name but different ProjectIDs were there. Facepalm

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. I clicked "Cancel", then refreshed the page. Project appeared under "Recent projects".

Answer (score 3):

The same issue happened to me today, but none of the answers was helpful. the problem is currently only project owner can create it.

I am the editor, that is why I am unable to create it.

[image]

Check your role in Project overview -> Users and permissions. if you are an editor ask the owner to create it.

> **Note**: This error did not happen to me when I create a new project. It happened to me when I create [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) in my firebase project. but I got the same error message(**There was an unknown error while processing the request try again**).
>
> If someone searches help by error message this answer may help to them. (I also got this question by searching the error message)

hope, it is helpful to someone!

Comment: Yes I agree. Open Firebase -> Choose your project -> Go to Project Settings -> Go to Users and Permissions and check your role assigned to you. If you're an editor than you are restricted to add new changes. You can only modified the existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Google Cloud Platform where I had exceeded my limits. Hence when I tried with other email ID. It worked Fine!!!!

I would suggest you to check the resources you have been utilizing by Google such as Firebase, G-Drive paid version, Google Cloud Platform etc.

Always, a new email ID is the best solution for practices purpose. No offense!

Answer (score 2):

Logging out and back in did not work for me.

However, I was able to link my project to Firebase via the Android Studio Firebase tool.

If you are using Android Studio, go to Tools > Firebase > (Select the way you want your app to use Firebase. In my case I selected Cloud Messaging) > Click Setup Firebase Cloud Messaging > Click the Button in Step 1) Connect You App to Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens for the first project created. Check your gmail  is there an email from Firebase to welcome you? If you get one, just wait for several hours (or 12 hours) to come back to re-try creating project.

This works for me. Hope it could help.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Firefox along with the [Disconnect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/) add-on. In my case, **adding Firebase webpage to the whitelist** helped resolving the problem.

[image]

Comment: In my case, I could not access the firebase console. This solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a limit on many projects you can upgrade to a paid plan in Firebase. I disocvered through my Google Cloud that I reached that limit but it also prompted to be request a higher quota. So I requested a max of 50 projects for paid plans and am now just wai

Answer (score 2):

I had an ad-block chrome extension that was creating this problem. **Disable ad-block** for this site and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Firebase Console with an account that is authorized by the owner, switching to the owner account (the one that has created the project at first) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I used incognito to prevent this error. This disables all the plugins from the browser.