# Can't add a new Firebase Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I go to the console.firebase to add a new project.  We already have 4 projects there.  We have a blaze account plan.  I put the name of the new project to add, accept the terms.  It starts creating the project, then fails with the message "There was an error creating the project (Reason: Unknown error)"

After several googling, I see that google say they resolved this error!  I don't see any suggested solutions.

[image]

I will greatly appreciate guidance on this

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115090/firebase-there-was-an-unknown-error-while-processing-the-request-try-again

Comment: If you see an error in the Firebase console, contact Firebase support directly.  Since this is not a programming question, it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/