# I am unable to create project in firebase?

Tags: firebase

As I was planning to host my web app in firebase I created a project. But due to some issues I deleted it and tried to create a new one but I was unable to create I tried many times but couldn't create it .

[image: The screenshot is here]

Then I created a new email address and again tried to create a project but despite it I was unable to create my project.

I am stuck in a limbo now anyone please help.

Comment: If you're having problems creating projects, always first check your JavaScript console for error message. Beyond that, it's unlikely anyone else here can help. [Reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43115090/7765316). There are many solutions to your current problem. try it

Answer (score 0):

It was happening with me because i was using Brave Browser.
Its shield was blocking all the requests being made while you create a firebase project.
Just disable the shield for google firebase webpage and you are good to go